# Rsync Synchronization issue between two servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rsync

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to Rsync from a remote to a local machine but been having issues with finding the synced files apparently.

The command I entered is:

```
sync -avzhe "~/var/test2/*" -e "ssh -i /etc/nginx/WhatsDue.pem" ubuntu@ec2********.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/test/
```

The command seems to be running properly:

```
    receiving incremental file list
drwxr-xr-x          4.10K 2015/02/25 19:15:48 .
-rwxrwxrwx             11 2015/02/25 19:15:48 test222.txt

sent 20 bytes  received 66 bytes  34.40 bytes/sec
total size is 11  speedup is 0.13
```

However, when I go to the "~/var/test2/" folder, I can't find the test222.txt file there.

Can you please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using -e option twice. Try with:

```
sync -avzh -e "ssh -i /etc/nginx/WhatsDue.pem" ~/var/test2/ ubuntu@ec2********.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/test/
```

Remember, ~/var/test2/ is local source and amazon instance (/var/test/ path) is the destination, so local ~/var/test2/ is not updated.

Good luck!